# How to limit the number of failed attempts to call a function?

Tags: python, python-2.x

How rewrite this code in a pythonic way?

```
tried = 0

while tried < 3:
    try:
        function()
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        tried += 1
```

Is there a built-in function I could use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more pythonic way to do something N times is to use `xrange` with the `_` variable:

```
for _ in xrange(3):
    try:
        function()
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Also, consider catching a more specific exception instead of the root `Exception` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [retry decorator](https://gist.github.com/n1ywb/2570004):

```
@retries(3)
def execTask():
    f()
```

One simpler than the one in the provided link could look like this:

```
def retry(times=3):
    def do_retry(f, *args, **kwargs):
        cnt = 0
        while cnt < times:
            try:
                f(*args, **kwargs)
                return
            except:
                cnt += 1
    return do_retry
```

And could be used like this:

```
@retry(3)
def test():
    print("Calling function")
    raise Exception("Some exception")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tried = 0

while tried < 3:
    try:
        function()   
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        tried += 1
```

It's almost exactly how you wrote it, except you need a colon at the end of your while line and move the break to the "try" block.

Answer (score -4):

### Motivation

Given the motivation of the OP was to **limit** the number of failing attempt to run a **`function()`**, the following code does not provide any artificial gymnastics, but both **limits** the number of tries and **retains** the actual number of attempts for ex-post analyses ( if needed down the road )

```
tried = 0

while tried < 3:
    try:
        function()           # may throw an Exception
        break                # on success pass through/return from  function()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        tried += 1
# retains a value of tried for ex-post review(s) if needed
```

Comment: You just copy pasted the example he gave. Try to provide a more useful solution.

Comment: @AndrewGrant not exactly, OP had several errors - both in code-syntax ( missing colon ) and in algorithmisation logic ( break in wrong place ). Being the first who answered, I just cannot believe my eyes how fast pathologic downvoting agony took place in this thread in the meantime...  An interesting lesson. **Anyway, enjoy PF2016, Andrew**

Comment: OP was clearly not confused as to how to accomplish his task. His question was whether or not there was a more 'pythonic' way of accomplishing it. Your answer is in no way pythonic.